# looking up data in different excel spreadsheets and returning information to the current worksheet

Tags: excel

In excel I want to create a quick look up sheet. I have various worksheets named by company with 12 months of data on each sheet with the months going across horizontally. I want the user to be able to enter a value in A1 corresponding to a worksheet name (company name). In cell A2 they will enter a month. The formula will find that worksheet, look up the month and return a value in the cell below it. What is the best way to approach this formula?

Comment: I think you may have to use VBA for that since one of your references is the name of a worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following formula:

```
=HLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("["&A1&"]Sheet1!$B$2:$C$3"),2,FALSE)
```

Let me break it down.

=HLOOKUP(... is a function that will find the value you are looking for based on the users inputs in cells A1 and A2.  This is a **H**orizontal**LOOKUP**.

A2... is the month that the user inputs and is what the HLOOKUP Formula will search for on the specified company worksheet.

INDIRECT("["&A1&"]... is a function that will allow the formula to dynamically change based on which company workbook is entered in cell A1.

Sheet1!$B$2:$C$3")... needs to be adjusted based on what the company worksheet is named.  For example you many have named your worksheets as the year 2014, so you would change 'Sheet1' to '2014'.  Also, the range $B$2:$C$3 will most likely be different in your example.  Make sure to adjust this range so that the top left most cell in the range is the first month and the bottom right most cell is the last month's data value that you would want returned.

,2... is the companies worksheet row you want to have returned (based on the range you gave in the previous step).

,FALSE)... tells the HLOOKUP function to look for an exact match.

Tip - make sure the values entered in cells A1 and A2 are exactly as they appear in the workbook name and month field.  Be sure to include the workbook extension .xlsx, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you looking for I will give you example for to company's files and you continue the same

the first company name will be comp1
[image: Company1 file]

the second company name will be comp2
[image: Company2 file]

And the master file will be as below
[image]

the formula is
 `=HLOOKUP(B2,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("[",A2,".xlsx]sheet1!$A$1:$L$2")),2,FALSE)`